# Overriding in inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

```
class X {

  int i;

public:

  X() { i = 0; }

  void set(int ii) { i = ii; }

  int read() const { return i; }

  int permute() { return i = i * 47; }
};
```

Above is the definition of class X

Another class Y is there as

```
class Y : public X {

    int i; // Different from X's i

public:

    Y() { i = 0; }

    int change() {
        i = permute(); // Different name call
        return i;
    }

    void set(int ii) {
        i = ii;
        X::set(ii); // Same-name function call
    }
};
```

My doubt is that class X also consists of a variable named i and it is been inherited by class Y, but i of class Y should overwrite it, but the size of class(Y) is coming 8.

Secondly, for the line

```
X::set(ii)
```

Can we call the function like this?
Is this function of class X invoked for any object?

Many many thanks in advance

Comment: Please indent your code! Indenting makes it sooo much more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Y::i` doesn't override anything (you can only override a virtual function). It *hides* `X::i`, so there are two different `i`s, one in the base class and one in the derived.

To your second question, outside of the class you can only use syntax like `X::set(ii);` when `set` is a `static` member function, not a normal or `virtual` member function. Inside the class you can use it to force a particular class' definition of the member function to be used.

Edit: I should probably answer the tricky (somewhat related) question: if the static type differs from the dynamic type, which `i` is used? For example, let's consider a simplified version:

```
class base { 
protected:  // we'll make `i` protected, so `derived` can access it if necessary.
    int i;
public:
    base() : i(0) {}
    void hide() { i = 2; }
    virtual void set() { i = 10; }
};

class derived : public base { 
    int i;
public:
    derived() : i(0) {}
    void hide() { i = 1; }
    void set() { i = 5; }
};
```

Now, since `set` is virtual, the call in `main` is to `derived::set`. Since `hide` is not virtual, the call in `main` will be to `base::hide()`. The question is, which class' `i` will each of them assign to?

The answer is fairly simple: even when the *function* is virtual, the variable is not, so each function refers to the variable in its own class. Having/lacking `virtual` controls which function you call, but not which variable is referred to by that function.

Comment: The last call is equivalent to `this->X::set(ii)` which is valid.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that there is no *overriding* in your code, only name *hiding*.

> My doubt is that class X also consists of a variable named i and it is been inherited by class Y, but i of class Y should overwrite it, but the size of class(Y) is coming 8.

Inheritance does not overwrite variables. The `i` in class `Y` will hide the name `i` from class `X`, but both will exist, hence the size of *8*.

> X::set(ii)
>   Can we call the function like this? Is this function of class X invoked for any object?

From within class `Y`, this *qualified call* request that the `set` from `X` is invoked in a static way instead of the `set` of `Y`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what does this mean set from X is invoked in a static way?

Comment: @Luv: Means that the resolution is _static_. If `set` where a `virtual` function, the call will invoke its definition from `X` and not any other `overriding` version.